# How to get component's variable in Angular 8 Web Components

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using Angular Web Components in version 8. I would like to reach out component's property from index.html. Here what I have;

There is component that has a property named **componentNames**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-name-provider',
  templateUrl: './component-name-provider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-name-provider.component.css']
})
export class ComponentNameProviderComponent implements OnInit {

  public componentNames: string[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.componentNames = ['name1', 'name2'];
  }
}
```

I have index.html that I would like to get **componentNames** (above mentioned) property from here.

```
<app-component-name-provider></app-component-name-provider>
<script>
    const el = document.querySelector('app-component-name-provider');
    el.componentNames // here I tried to perform but did not work, el is null
</script>
```

I am also dropping app.module.ts if it is needed;

```
import { Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ComponentNameProviderComponent } from './component-name-provider/component-name-provider.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ComponentNameProviderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
  entryComponents: [
    ComponentNameProviderComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const componentNameProviderComponentCustomElement = createCustomElement(ComponentNameProviderComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('app-component-name-provider', componentNameProviderComponentCustomElement);
  }
}
```

I've tried to explain what I've. I am looking a way to get **componentNames** property from index.html. As I tried above, I am not able to get the variable by getting *document.querySelector*

I am aware I can use @Output decorator on event emitter however I don't think it is best practice for this purpose.

Is there any solution about my question? Thanks for all helps and inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ViewChild to get componentNames property.
You have to add localReference to your component like below.

```
<app-component-name-provider #testName></app-component-name-provider>

@ViewChild('testName', {static:true}) testName;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.testName); // you will get your component properties here
  }
```

Link to the answer:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubzhfd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts